# Routing issue over an IPsec tunnel

Tags: routing, mac-osx, nat, ipsec, routeros

I am using RouterOS as IPSec responder in the cloud with 2 interfaces:

- Ethernet1: 10.128.255.4/24 (+public IP mapped by the cloud infrastructure and mentioned bellow as gw1.public.ip.addr)
- Ethernet2: 10.128.0.35/24
- IPSec pool: 10.127.1.1/24

...but just hosts from 10.128.255.0/24 are reachable for IPSec clients. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

```
[da@gw1] /interface> list print 
Flags: * - builtin, D - dynamic 
# List Interface                                                      
0   PUBAN   ehter1                                                    
1   PRVAN   ehter2
```

Filter Rules:

```
[da@gw1] /ip firewall> filter print 
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
0 X  chain=output action=accept log=no log-prefix="" 

1 ;;; IPsec
chain=input action=accept protocol=udp dst-port=500,4500 log=no log-prefix="" 

2 ;;; IPsec
chain=input action=accept protocol=ipsec-esp log=no log-prefix="" 

3 ;;; IPsec to Public
chain=forward action=accept src-address=10.127.1.0/24 dst-address=10.128.0.0/24 log=no log-prefix="" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec 

 4 ;;; IPsec to Private
chain=forward action=accept src-address=10.127.1.0/24 dst-address=10.128.255.0/24 log=no log-prefix="" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec 

5 ;;; IPsec to gw1
chain=input action=accept src-address=10.127.1.0/24 log=no log-prefix="" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
```

NAT:

```
[da@gw1] /ip firewall> nat print 
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
0 X  ;;; SRC-NAT IPsec traffic
  chain=srcnat action=src-nat to-addresses=gw1.public.ip.addr src-address=10.127.1.0/24 out-interface=ether1 log=no log-prefix="" 

1 ;;; Masquerade IPsec traffic
  chain=srcnat action=masquerade src-address=10.127.1.0/24 out-interface-list=PUBAN log=no log-prefix="" ipsec-policy=out,none 

2 chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=PUBAN 

3 ;;; Masquerade IPsec traffic
  chain=srcnat action=masquerade src-address=10.127.1.0/24 out-interface-list=PRVAN log=no log-prefix="" ipsec-policy=out,none 

4 chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=PRVAN log=no log-prefix=""
```

Routes:

```
Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          10.128.255.1              1
1  DS  0.0.0.0/0                          10.128.0.1                1
2 ADC  10.127.1.0/24      10.127.1.1      bridge1                   0
3 ADC  10.128.0.0/24      10.128.0.35     ether2                    0
4 ADC  10.128.255.0/24    10.128.255.4    ether1                    0
```

macOS connected successfully and has such routes in the table:

```
~ ❯ netstat -rn                                                                                                                                                                        Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGScg             en0       
default            link#26            UCSIg          ipsec0       
10.127.1.236       10.127.1.236       UH             ipsec0       
10.128/24          10.127.1.236       UGSc           ipsec0       
10.128.255/24      10.127.1.236       UGSc           ipsec0       
gw1.public.ip.addr 192.168.1.1        UGHS              en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#15            UCS               en0      !
192.168.1          link#15            UCS               en0      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#15            UCS               en0      !
192.168.1.1        e8:1:8d:e8:7e:98   UHLWIir           en0   1186
192.168.1.6        70:3e:97:6d:13:4a  UHLWIi            en0    935
192.168.1.10/32    link#15            UCS               en0      !
192.168.1.11       bc:d0:74:76:af:95  UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.1.12       46:22:57:2a:9d:84  UHLWI             en0   1026
192.168.1.13       9e:b3:47:e1:5a:4f  UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.1.14       9e:40:a1:46:f5:98  UHLWI             en0      !
192.168.1.15       2:85:20:14:df:b5   UHLWIi            en0    939
192.168.1.16       5e:8e:ac:4a:72:6a  UHLWI             en0   1129
192.168.1.17       ce:b2:89:4d:9a:d1  UHLWI             en0   1129
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS              en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#26            UmCSI          ipsec0       
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en0       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS               en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#26            UCSI           ipsec0
```